# Write the null hypothesis for nested model test in algebraic form

Tags: anova, mixed-model, categorical-data, linear-model, fixed-effects-model

The reduced model is: `lm(y~Age+Sex, data = df)`;

The full model is: `lm(y~Age+Sex+Age*Sex, data = df)`.

(`y` and `Age` are continuous variables, and `Sex` is a categorical variable with two levels: *Male and Female*.)

I use command `anova()` in R to compare these two models:

```r
> fit_full <- lm(y~Age*Sex, data = df)
> fit_full

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ Age * Sex, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          Age         SexM     Age:SexM  
    0.23994      1.12808     -0.06575     -0.05118  

> fit_reduced <- lm(y~Age+Sex, data = df)
> fit_reduced

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ Age + Sex, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          Age         SexM  
     0.2856       1.0988      -0.1486  

> anova(fit_reduced,fit_full)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: y ~ Age + Sex
Model 2: y ~ Age * Sex
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     77 137.00                           
2     76 136.99  1  0.012219 0.0068 0.9346
```

I only know we can see if the interaction term is significant or not from the output, **but I don't know how to write down the null hypothesis in algebraic form, and how to write the algebraic expressions of these two models(reduced model and full model**).Can someone help me with these questions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing two models with the fact that 'reduced model' is nested in 'full model', being the only difference between both is the Age:SexM term. So, the null hypothesis should be $H_0:\beta(Age:SexM) = 0$